# On Win32 how do you move a thread to another CPU core?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, multicore

I'd like to make sure that a thread is moved to a specific CPU core and can never be moved from it by the scheduler.

There's a `SetThreadAffinityMask()` call but there's no `GetThreadAffinityMask()`.

The reason I need this is because high resolution timers will get messed up if the scheduler moves that thread to another CPU.

Comment: You don't *need* GetThreadAffinityMask(), only SetThreadAffinityMask().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should probably just use SetThreadAffinityMask and trust that it is working.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684251.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you could call a function that returns a number indicating what CPU the thread is running on, without using affinity, the answer would often be wrong as soon as the function returned. So checking the mask returned by `SetThreadAffinityMask()` is as close as you're going to get, outside of kernel code running at elevated IRQL, and [even that's changing](http://kernelmustard.com/2008/09/30/bad-idea-making-assumptions-about-cpu-number/).

It sounds like you're trying to work around `RDTSC` clock skew issues. If you are using the `RDTSC` instruction directly, consider calling `QueryPerformanceCounter()` instead:

- `QueryPerformanceCounter()` on Windows Vista uses the [HPET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) if it is supported by the chipset and is in the system's ACPI tables.
- AMD-based systems using the [AMD Processor Driver](http://www.amd.com/us-en/Processors/TechnicalResources/0,,30_182_871_9706,00.html) will mostly compensate for multi-core clock skew if you call `QueryPerformanceCounter()`, but this does nothing for applications that use `RDTSC` directly. The [AMD Dual-Core Optimizer](http://www.amd.com/us-en/Processors/TechnicalResources/0,,30_182_871_9706,00.html) is a hack for applications that use `RDTSC` directly, but if the amount of clock skew is changing due to C1 clock ramping (where the clock speed is reduced in the C1 power state), you will still have clock skew. And these utilities probably aren't very widespread, so using affinity with `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is still a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

What Ken said. But if you don't trust it's working, you can call SetThreadAffinityMask again, and confirm that the return value matches what you expect the mask to be. (But then of course, if you don't trust the function then you can't trust the second call...)

Don't be confused by the existence of GetProcessAffinityMask. That function is not there to verify that SetProcessAffinityMask worked, but e.g. so you can construct a thread affinity that is a subset of process affinity.

Just look that the return value and verify that it isn't 0 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for Get*Thread*AffinityMask. Just get the value of Get*Process*AffinityMask, turn some bits off, then call SetThreadAffinityMask. The threads inherit the process' affinity mask, and since their affinity is under your control, you already know a thread's affinity mask (it's the one you set it to).